# How best to display a file hash

Tags: encoding, hash, base64

Simple question. What is the best (most universal) way to display a file hash? Below are two SHA256 hashes for the same file. One is displayed as base64 and one is...something else. The file hash will be used for auditing to make sure the file we send is the same as the file the auditor received. If the hash needs to be verified, I want to make sure I provide the hash that is the most easily verifiable.

```
SHA256          55461e72cccb74b475278189956b9db307bf44945e1639af93c34b224b7fcfd
SHA256 Base 64  VUYecszLdLR1J4GJlWudswe/RJReFjmvk8NLIkt/z9s=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

55461e72cccb74b475278189956b9db307bf44945e1639af93c34b224b7fcfd

The point of Base64 is to constrain the character set to displayable characters. The hash is in hexadecimal which is even more constrained.